# Does AppExchange Checkout works only for the Production Org (Paid Orgs)?

Tags: managed-package, appexchange, production, pricing

We have created a Second Generation Managed Package and we want it to be available as paid version on AppExchange Portal. So we thought of using AppExchange Checkout Platform, but in the [Documentations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/appexchange_checkout_faq_active_orgs.htm) it is mentioned that "**If a customer clicks Get It Now on your listing, but can't make a Checkout purchase, verify that the customer is logged in to AppExchange with a supported Salesforce org. Checkout supports only paid orgs whose status is Active. Trial orgs, sandbox orgs, and Developer Edition orgs aren't supported.**"

Does this mean our managed package solution can be installed only in Production Orgs or a user can install it in any org if he logs into AppExchange Portal from Production Org (Paid Org) and update,renew the licenses etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salesforce allows you to install AppExchange apps in unpaid orgs (e.g. Developer Edition) for evaluation and/or testing purposes. It's not uncommon for an organization to choose to install an app in a Sandbox to make sure the app won't conflict with their own customizations and code. In this case, the app is in an "evaluation mode" that has unlimited licenses with no expiration. When they install the app in a paid org, they will need to purchase the needed licenses to use the app.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @sfdcfox, Can you please explain this line a bit more "In this case, the app is in an evaluation mode that has unlimited licenses with no expiration". Does this mean a paid app with pricing plan as (per user per month) with 30 days trail period can be installed in sandbox org for free of cost with unlimited licenses and with no expiration?

Comment: @S1th Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Thanks you so much for the reply @sfdcfox.

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox , we thought of using AppExchange Checkout for handling payments so we have registered our Managed Package with LMA (License Management Application). But now we want to handle the payments ourself. So we want to use Channel Order App. Does registering an app with LMA impact anyway? and how to connect our Managed Package to COA. In this link (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/coa_import_data.htm) it is mentioned to connect Salesforce regarding Product Catalog. Could you please explain this.

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox,  I have asked the same thing as another question (https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/413351/does-registering-a-package-in-lma-impacts-anyway-if-we-use-channel-order-app-to).