# Does registering a package in LMA impacts anyway if we use Channel Order APP to handle payments?

Tags: managed-package, appexchange, licenses, lma, pricing

We thought of using AppExchange Checkout for handling payments so we have registered our Managed Package with LMA (License Management Application). We didn't publish our listing yet. But now we want to handle the payments ourself. So we want to use Channel Order App.

I have few doubts.

1. Does registering an app with LMA impact anyway if we want to use COA?
2. How to connect our Managed Package to COA?
3. In this [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/coa_import_data.htm), it is mentioned to connect Salesforce COA Production Org to sync the Product Catalog (Our Managed Package Solution).How to relate our Managed Package to COA Production Org?
4. If we use COA, does changing the number of licenses in a license record of LMA will increase the licenses in Customers Org or does the licenses increase after Salesforce processes the corresponding submitted order through COA?
5. How does LMA relate to COA?